# Webdriver: finding and clicking hidden element, where id constantly changing

Tags: java, selenium, dynamic, webdriver, element

i am newbie to selenium webdriver, i am struggling to find a button on the webpage, because its Id is constantly changing and there is no other attributes available to use to identify this element. please see below code.
could someone look at this code and help me how to identify this button element.

[selenium webdriver hidden elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGnAw.png)

Comment: What about finding the button from the text on it ?

Comment: where is your code??

Comment: @Aravindh unable to find it either from the link text.

Comment: @Software_Engineer i have attached the image of html code.

Comment: referring the code you have mentioned, if you want to select the first button, you can find using class name. To get first button use `.header-navigation .btn.cta_buttons__link--button-1`

Comment: @Ivar -  what have you tried?

Comment: @SandeepSukhija i tried cssSelector, linkText and className but no luck. driver.findElement(By.className(".header-navigation .btn.cta_buttons__link--button-1")).click();

Comment: I had a typo, edit the class names as `.header-navigation__cta-buttons .btn.cta-buttons__link--button-1`

Comment: what is the error you are getting.  does it not find the element, or report a failure to click on it?

Comment: i did try as above, however i get the following error "The given selector .header-navigation__cta-buttons .btn.cta-buttons__link--button-1 is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted"

Comment: @Ivar you are using compound class name to find the element which does not work  `By.className`.. you should try some different locator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try by `xPath` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1000);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xPath("//div[contains(@class, 'header-navigation__cta-buttons-wrapper')]/a[contains(@class, 'cta-buttons__link--button-1')]")));
el.click();
```

**Be sure this element is not inside a frame..**

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: tbh as a newbie i dont understand the code. but i copy pasted your code and it works. Thank you so much!! now i am able to click the button, which populates a contact us form, now i need to try and identify other items in the form, hopefully with your code :)

Comment: @Ivar Please accept the answer...if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: why we using WebDriverWait and ExpectedConditions ? i never heard of these. i will dig through internet first and come back to you. Thanks for your help! you are a legend!!

Comment: @Ivar  Some time when you navigete in webPage the element which you want to locate is not be fully loaded on page due to slow internet or other reason..at this time if will go to find element with correct locator..It seems to element not found while your logic is correct... so that's why we are using `WebDriverWait` to wait till element be fully loaded on the page and then going to find elements..

Comment: @Ivar Selenium provides concept of `ExpectedConditions`.. that how you want to wait for an element....you should follow this link for better understanding about all conditions.. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html